# get-adgroup -filter "SID -like '*-512'"

Tags: powershell, filter, sid

I have been wanting to figure out how to use `-filter` to get what I want. What I am trying to do is find the `Domain Admins` group by a `-like` statement of `*-512` against the SID property using the following:

```
get-adgroup -filter "SID -like '*-512'"
```

It works if I put the actual SID

```
get-adgroup -filter "SID -eq 'S-1-5-21domain-512'"
```

I know doing it this way will work

```
get-adgroup -filter * | ? {$_.SID -like '*-512'}
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems

Comment: The last code snippet you have. I would do.... Get-ADGroup -filter * | Where {$_.SID -like "*512*"}   ...is there a reason you're looking for a different way to accomplish this? The first code snippet works perfectly for me as well. Another option is using $_.Name instead of SID if you now the group name.

Comment: The issue is that `SID` isn't stored as as a string, I believe it's stored as binary `[byte]`. So you can't do a `-like` in the filter. But your method with the `Where-Object` works.

Comment: Yeah, after a little more research. More information can be found [here on MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428139%28WS.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Relevant section:  "Because the SIDs are stored in the LDAP database as binary data, you need to use the raw, little Endian format of the SID to search the directory."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [BenH comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244354/get-adgroup-filter-sid-like-512#comment77457806_45244354), you cannot partially filter on SIDs in LDAP queries, because of [the way SID values are stored](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684453(v=vs.85).aspx) in the directory. The SID string you see is an SDDL representation of an underlying byte array.

I assume your motivation for attempting wildcard matching against a well-known RID is that you don't know the domain SID in advance. You can easily obtain that with the `Get-ADDomain` cmdlet:

```
$DomainSID = (Get-ADDomain).DomainSID
$DomainAdminsSid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::AccountDomainAdminsSid,$DomainSID)

Get-ADGroup -Filter {SID -eq $DomainAdminsSid}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias for your explanation